# Will I be charged if I delete the document from Firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I saw that the method of deleting documents in batches should be a for repetition statement.

But is it charged even if the administrator deletes the document like in the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. As stated on this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations):

> You are charged for each document read, write, and delete that you perform with Cloud Firestore.
> Charges for writes and deletes are straightforward. For writes, each set or update operation counts as a single write.

If you **delete** a document on Firestore Console then it's still considered a **delete operation**. You will not be charged for the delete operation if and only if the delete operation **failed**.

---

For more information, you may check [Understand Cloud Firestore billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing).